# django urls.py regex isn't working

Tags: python, django

This is for Django 1.2.5 and Python 2.7 on Wamp Server running apache version 2.2.17.

My problem is that the my URLConf in urls.py isn't redirecting, it's just throwing a 404 error.

**urls.py:**

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
#from django.contrib import admin
#admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^app/$', include('app.views.index')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    #(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    #(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello World")
```

I'm getting the following error:
ImportError at /app/
No module named index

I'm stumped as I'm only learning Django, can anybody see something wrong with my code? Here's my PythonPath:
    ['C:\Windows\system32\python27.zip', 'C:\Python27\Lib', 'C:\Python27\DLLs', 'C:\Python27\Lib\lib-tk', 'C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.17', 'C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.17\bin', 'C:\Python27', 'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages', 'c:\wamp\www\seetwo']

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, your url should look like this:

```
(r'^app/$', 'app.views.index'),
```

Using the `include` statement means you are pointing to a new urlconf file!
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs

So it's looking for a module `index` which doesn't exist (as opposed to a function if you didn't use `include()`)

Comment: Boom, there it is! Fixed now, thanks Yuji I'll accept you answer in approx 7 minutes when I'm allowed. :)